# How do I get the list of Associated Domains entitlements programmatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to make sure that a given domain name specified in the entitlements for an app – under *Associated Domains > Domains* with an `applinks:` prefix – is in the list.

How can I do this programmatically in Swift (~5)?

Comment: Did you find the way to do it?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to find them programmatically @tomacco

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can be done programmatically, but if you go to 
https://developer.apple.com/ -> *My Apps* -> *Choose your app* -> *Activity* -> then choose any build number, it will show you the domains associated with your app (when that build was submitted).